# Using parametrized type as generic type in Java

Tags: java, generics

I have a short question concerning Java Genrerics:

Is there any way to get grip on the type of a type-parameter's also generic type? Hard to explain, short example: ;-)

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class GenericContainer<C extends Collection<T>, T> {

    C collection;

    public GenericContainer(C collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    // I need both: the type of the collection's elements...
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return collection.add(t);
    }

    // ... and the type of the collection. 
    public C getCollection() {
        return this.collection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Here it comes:
        // Is it possible to remove the redundant "String" in the generic declaration?
        GenericContainer<List<String>, String> container = new GenericContainer<>(Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar"));
    }
}
```

So, as said in the comments, my goal is to have this simpler version:
`GenericContainer<List<String>> container` instead of `GenericContainer<List<String>, String> container` with redundant String. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you actually remove the second parameter? (and remove it from class declaration too ofc): `public class GenericContainer<C extends Collection<T>>`. I believe it won't work because your compiler can't know in advance the type of the List, but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can't because one generic type references the container, the other the elements in the container. So you have two types hence two separate arguments.

Comment: Is there a reason you need `C` specifically? If not, you could just have `<T>` on your class and use `Collection<T>` everywhere where you now have `C`.

Comment: Yes - users of that class require to know C to not loose methods of their specific implementation, e.g. List has more methods than Collection.